# Live-server can't run typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm taking my first steps with typescript anintmente I used JavaScript, the problem is that JavaScript to me runs it perfectly live-server which i'm using as an extension of visual code, and now that I'm using typescript pulls me this error:

[image: Script from "http://localhost:5500/js/holamundo.ts" was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type ("video/mp2t")]

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile your Typescript before running it in the browser. Your web server doesn't know the correct MIME type for sending the image, but that's ok because the browser wouldn't understand it anyway.

Comment: ohhhh already thank you then you have to compile it first by the terminal, thank you very much first time I use TS!!

Comment: Always compiling with the terminal is time waste. Look out for webpack 4 and make yourself a config!

Comment: ohhh okay okay thanks so much